# Подлежащее или дополнение?

Tags: синтаксис

Каким членом предложения будет являться слово "ничего" в предложении: "С опытным проводником нам не страшно ничего: ни броды через бурные реки, ни сплошная тайга, ни перевалы"?
Подлежащее или дополнение? Ведь броды, тайга, перевалы - подлежащее...

Answer (score 10):

Тайга не страшна, брод не страшен - ничто не страшно. Считаю, что это двусоставное предложение. Просто вместо формы "ничто" с каких -то пор в качестве подлежащего стала употребляться и форма "ничего".

Подобно происходит и в других случаях. Например,  форма "чего" в разговорной речи вытесняет и местоименное наречие "что": что ты пришел? - чего ты пришел?

Comment: Тайга не страшна, брод не страшен - ничто не страшно.

это бессоюзное предложение с тремя грамматические основами:

1. тайга не страшна
2. брод не страшен
3. ничто не страшно.

Comment: С опытным проводником нам не страшно ничего: ни броды через бурные реки, ни сплошная тайга, ни перевалы.

это безличное предложение с грамматической основой _не страшно".

_ничего:ни броды через бурные реки, ни сплошная тайга, ни перевалы_ - это один член, а именно дополнение.
Обобщающее слово и однородные члены являются одним членом предложения.

Comment: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200302310:

если местоимение в именительном падеже, то это позиция подлежащего, если же местоимение в косвенном падеже – позиция дополнения. 

Примеры. 

Я открыл футлярчик. В нем лежало что-то завернутое в нечто белоснежное и легчайшее (Д.Гранин); 

что-то завернутое в нечто белоснежное и легчайшее - подлежащее

 Ничего плохого в письме не было.

Ничего плохого - дополнение.

Comment: Вы это о чём? Ваша ссылка о неделимых сочетаниях.(я с ней согласна:Ничего плохого в письме не было.Не было чего?-ничего плохого - дополн. в род. п.)Только как Вы её применили к категории состояния? Это "не страшно ничего"- неделимое сочетание? и какую позицию оно занимает? Сказуемого? И все однородные члены сказуемые? Вот уж... Даже слов нет, какой научный подход.

Answer (score 4):

Несмотря на явно выраженный "неименительный" падеж вопрос к "ничего" - вопрос именителного падажа: не страшно *что?*  (не страшен *кто?*). Это ещё одно доказательство того, что  *ничего* - подлежащее. 
  А насчёт обощающего слова я вообще не поняла, что Вы, behemothus, хотели сказать. И с точки зрения грамматики, и с точки зрения синтаксиса, и с точки зрения пунктуации, и со многих других точек зрения  это обобщающее слово.

Comment: 1. Грамматика не позволяет подлежащему стоять не в именительном падеже.
2. "И с точки зрения грамматики"... Давайте ей пока и ограничимся. 
Уберите обобщающее слово (если 'то оно грамматика не пострадает): *Ни броды через бурные реки, ни сплошная тайга, ни перевалы нам не страшно.* Нормально?  
*У меня не было ни пера, ни бумаги, ни чернил: ничего не было.* В чем разница? Или здесь "ничего" тоже подлежащее?

Comment: Нет, здесь дополнение. И однородные члены дополнения. И пунктуация у Вас непонятная: объясните постановку двоеточия (по правилам должно быть тире).   
Ларf говорит же Вам, что словом "ничего" стали заменять слово "ничто". Попробуйте в Вашем предложении заменить.
А теперь попробуйте заменить словом "всё".  В первом предложении оно в им. п., а Вашем - в родительном. И попробуйте опровергнуть тот факт, что слово "всё" является обобщающим.

Comment: Пунктуация - из примера. Там двоеточие.   
Впрочем, пусть будет по правилам. 
Остальное - непонятно. Сказуемое согласуется (координируется) с подлежащим, а не с обобщающим словом. Именно это я и пытался показать своим примером.

Answer (score 3):

С опытным проводником нам не страшно ничего: ни броды через бурные реки, ни сплошная тайга, ни перевалы. В школьной грамматике такие предложения рассматриваются как двусоставные с подлежащим в застывшей форме родит. падежа, употреблённой в разговорной речи:

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200403204

"Ничего" по Ожегову- два омонима: 1.-разговорное наречие(чувствует себя ничего;ничего себе правда; пусть придёт, ничего); 2-разговорное НЕИЗМЕНЯЕМОЕ отрицательное местоимение, то же, что НИЧТО.

Это как раз такой случай - неизменяемое, т. е. родительный п.= именительному. В разговорном мы и не то ещё встретим: Пусть их, собаки, с голоду передохнут; Пусть ее, негодная, и на глаза мне не показывается. Их, её - это дополнение или всё же подлежащее?
 Приложение после местоимений указывает на то, что это в роли именит.падежа, значит, 
подлежащее.(Пусть собаки передохнут)

НЕ СТРАШНО  что?- всё: и броды, и тайга, и перевалы. В отрицательных конструкциях НИ иногда заменяет союз И, а ничего заменяет ВСЁ.. Функция одна и та же. Значит, НИЧЕГО- подлежащее.

Comment: Не проходит.
>2-разговорное НЕИЗМЕНЯЕМОЕ отрицательное местоимение, то же, что НИЧТО.  
  
Неизменяемое - это значит во всех падежах - "ничего". Но оно возможно только в родительном. Если принять концепцию, о которой тут говорилось, то надо бы говорить о местоимении с неполной парадигмой (нет падежей кроме именительного).   
Хотя я сказал, почему мне не нравится эта идея. Падеж на самом деле вполне себе родительный: "нам не страшно ни тайги, ни перевалов...". А вот первая часть не стыкуется в падеже со второй. Что и дало повод утверждать, что грамматика тут нарушена.

Comment: Это Вы спорите не со мной, а с Ожеговым, он назвал неизменяемым, а я согласна. А вот "нам не страшно ни тайги, ни перевалов" - уже разговорная конструкция, во-первых, а во-вторых, вопрос о конструкции "нам не страшно что?-ничего. Что именно?- броды, тайга, перевалы". Когда-то здесь бы и ударение поставили "страшнО"(если убрать союзы).Нам страшно тайги - звучит странно (просторечно).Нужно: "нас страшит тайга", "нам страшна тайга". Страшно может быть ОНО, а не ЕГО. Конструкция эта разговорная, что о ней говорить.

Comment: Если "Нам страшно" - безличная конструкция, то посмотрим на сочетаемость категории состояния.(Надеюсь, это категория состояния, а не краткое прилагательное? - это ведь признак безличности?) Категория состояния (по Валгиной и Розенталю)"может распространяться формами имён сущ. и местоимений в дат. пад. без предлога (кому?-нам)и в род.пад и предл. с предлогами" (у кого?, где?-у нас, в тайге). Как видите, "страшно чего?" нет.

Comment: >Это Вы спорите не со мной, а с Ожеговым, он назвал неизменяемым,   
  
Боже избави. Вы еще скажите, что я против Советской власти.
Я вообще по поводу определений не спорю. Только Ожегов не писал, что слово в Вашей конструкции является тем самым "неизменяемым" и именительным падежом.     

По поводу всего остального. Я бы ответил, но не на что. По вашему получается, что конструкция с родительным падежом в качестве подлежащего - это нормально, а "нестрашно чего" - разговорная и поэтому неправильна?  А почему не наоборот? Только не говорите, что я спорю еще с каким евангелистом.

Comment: >Надеюсь, это категория состояния, а не краткое прилагательное? - это ведь признак безличности?   
  
Не знаю... Это терминология. Хоть горшком назови. Ну пусть будет категория состояния.  

>Категория состояния (по Валгиной и Розенталю)"может распространяться формами имён сущ. и местоимений в дат....

Не понял. Это что-то объясняет или опровергает в моей логике?

Comment: Опровергает возможность сочетания категории состояния с родительным падежом без предлога,это противоречит норме, но возможно в разговорном стиле, потому что там "не страшно ничего" = "не страшнО что" - двусоставная конструкция. Потому обобщающее слово - подлежащее нормально согласуется с однородными подлежащими.Просто вместо разговорного нужно иметь в виду нормированную форму местоимения.

Comment: >Опровергает возможность сочетания категории состояния с родительным падежом  
  
Никоим образом. Максиму - объясняет, чем в данной конструкции явняется "нам". Про родительный (точнее - невозможность его) я что-то ничего не вижу.

Хорошо, допустим, на минутку, что родительный без предлога при категории состояния невозможен, а страшно чего - нарушение грамматики. 

"Мне было боязно волка".  - это как?

Отвечаю всем здесь. http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=3687

Answer (score 2):

Нет, *"броды"*, *"тайга"* и *"перевалы"*, как и *"ничего"*, являются дополнениями. Подлежащего в этом предложении нет, и это одно предложение, а не бессоюзное, как вы, наверное, подумали.

Comment: Им. падеж - тайга, род. - тайги, винит. - тайгу. В предложении существительные в именительном падеже. Это подлежащие!

Comment: Да. Это понятно. А как насчет "ничего"?
Вот так вот запросто поставить подлежащее в косвенном падеже - это уже  перебор, пожалуй...

Comment: Тем не менее почему-то стали употреблять. Строго правильно - ничто.

Answer (score -3):

"...нам не страшно ничего" - я бы классифицировал это предложение как безличное. 
Есть такой тип безличных с отрицанием. Это обсуждаемо, тут могут быть разные подходы.
Но вот с тем, что это подлежащее я бы никак не согласился. Даже в форме именительного падежа (ничто) это скорее предикатив.

Поскольку дискуссия явно перешла в стадию "Наших бьют" и отвечать на вопросы уже нет ни возможности, ни целесообразности, попробую напоследок разжевать то, что оказалось непонятным.

Итак.
~1. Подлежащее принимать родительный падеж не может. Хотел было оговориться, что это не винительный, но это, пожалуй, и так понятно. Подлежащее может стоять только в именительном падеже, этот грамматический закон настолько силён, что никакое просторечие, никакие исторические формы не могут его преобразовать. Другое дело, что тут могут появиться какие-то другие грамматические формы, ранее не известное языку управление...

~2. Почему родительный. Возьмем сразу прошедшее время, тут, надеюсь, возражений по сути не будет.
*"...ничего не было страшно: ни тайга, ни перевалы..."*

Первая часть фразы, не будь там ничего звучала бы "Не было страшно ни тайги, ни перевалов...". Это совсем не та форма, на которой настаивают утверждающие, что  заменено на "ничего" просто по прихоти говорящего. Чем бы тут ни было это "ни тайга", "ни перевалы" - уж никак не подлежащим. И родительный падеж очевиден. 
Вопрос насколько представленное нормативно, не обсуждаю: уж по крайней никак не менее нормативно, чем родительный в подлежащем.

~3. Вторая часть фразы явно грамматически не согласуется с первой. Скорее всего она взята из другой фразы (*Ни тайга, ни перевалы: нас ничто не пугало*) и искусственно "пришита" к первой.

~4. Вопрос тем, кто всё еще думает, что разговоры про замену "ничто" на "ничего" что-то объясняют.
*Ничего не (было) видно*. Здесь тоже "Ничего" подлежащее? А в "Не было видно тайги, перевалов...*?

//----
Остаётся открытым вопрос, почему эти формы реально путаются. Полагаю, что здесь действительно происходит что-то с грамматикой... Но это надо думать... 
Хотя не удивлюсь, если через несколько лет умные дяди опишут новый тип односоставного (безличного?) предложения или признают возможность некоего "дополнения" при конструкциях предикативных сказуемого "было страшно [волка]" как "было видно [волка]"

Я постараюсь ответить на вопросы по представленной логике, остальные вынужден буду игнорировать или отвечать в другом месте.

А возразить-то, похоже нечего. Только минусяки ставить тайно ))).

**//========== 12.02.2013**

А между тем вопрос-то вполне разрешился благодаря slava1947, еще раз - респект. Как же мне самому не стукнуло в голову посмотреть а АГ...

Семантическая структура

§ 2578. Семантика схемы - "наличие состояния - бессубъектного или отнесенного к субъекту" - конкретизируется в предложении как состояние бессубъектное (Морозно; Сыро; Тепло; Похоже на сумерки; Пусть будет так) или субъектное (Весело; Неловко; Ему и невдомек). При распространении субъектным детерминантом формируется семантическая структура "субъект - его непроцессуальное состояние (внутреннее, внешнее, воспринимаемое извне, физическое)": Детям весело; С отцом/отцу плохо; С этой семьей неблагополучно; Для посетителей/посетителям удобно; Автору виднее; На душе/в душе (у нее) тоскливо. В эту структуру может входить объект: ***Мне даже и смерти не страшно***, Она, как и жизнь, позади (Твард.); Ему стыдно перед окружающими; С жильем у них хорошо; С этим человеком мне неинтересно; Нам об этом неизвестно.

В предложениях с двойной детерминацией типа Мне ногам холодно; Ему голове неудобно; Тебе плечам не больно? субъектное значение несет детерминант со значением лица (ср.: Мне плечи больно; § 2439).

Предложения с предикативным наречием вступают в формально-семантические соотношения с глагольными предложениями - при условии лексического соответствия наречия и глагола: Мне стыдно перед соседями - Я стыжусь соседей; Ему тоскливо - Он тоскует; Ему больно спине - У него болит спина. Однако полные смысловые наложения здесь, как и в других случаях, исключены - из-за расхождения семантики структурных схем у предложений глагольных и неглагольных.

(Курсив мой, b-s)

А вообще там весь раздел стоит почитать. Начиная с § 2574. 
http://rusgram.narod.ru/2567-2590.html

Comment: Ничто - обобщающее слово при однородных членах, должно стоять в той же форме, являться тем же членом предложения.  Тайга, брод - ничто - одна форма, один член предложения.

Comment: >Ничто - обобщающее слово при однородных членах,   
 
Вряд ли... если бы "ничто" стояло сразу после перечисления: "ничто не страшно", я бы согласился не задумываясь. Но тут грамматика, похоже, другая. Если она вообще тут есть. По грамматике получается, сказуемое не согласуется (или как теперь говорят - не координируется) подлежащим... "Не *страшны* ни тайга, ни перевалы... ", но "ничего не *страшно*". Может это вообще два предложения?

Comment: Сказуемое согласуется с обобщающим словом. Опять же задайте вопрос от сказуемого к подлежащему. Это будет вопрос именительного падежа, а никак не родительного. Вот произошла такая трансформация со словом "ничто" в языке, и ничего тут не поделаешь. Остаётся только признать этот очевидный факт. Вместо того, чтобы настаивать на своём, приводя малоубедительные примеры.

Comment: Бегемотус! Обобщающее слово может стоять и перед однородными членами.

Comment: Алена7, Вы потрясающе оригинальны. Я что, где-то писал, что не может?  Но в **данном случае** я считаю, что здесь нечто иное. И объяснил, почему.   

Но спасибо хоть за то, что перестали минусы тайно ставить.

Элен, хоть десять раз повторите, "халва" - во рту слаще не станет. Тезис "произошла трансформация" я понимаю. Но не принимаю, поскольку голословие. Там винительный падеж по смыслу - никуда не денешься, даже после двадцати заявлений о трансформации. Остальное - просто не могу признать относящимся к делу.
А что вам показалось неубедительным в примерах?

Comment: Здесь технически невозможно вести дискуссии. Попробую перенести дискусии на "Грамоту". Или в любое другое место, где есть возможность соблюдать последовательность треда...

Comment: А вы за все свои 99 минусов отчитались?

Comment: Никогда не ставил тайных минусов.